# how to limit number of threads in polars

Tags: python-polars

Is there a way to limit the number of threads used by polars?

I am doing this because I am doing a second layer of parallelization around some polars code, and would like to limit the inner parallelism. This should still be better than Pandas due to the SIMD right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the env var `POLARS_MAX_THREADS`. This value initializes the thead pool size. This must be set before polars is imported.

More configuration env vars are documented [here](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/#config-with-env-vars).

Comment: Is it possible to do it programatically?

Comment: No, the threadpool is created on startup and cannot be modified later.

Comment: Of course, it is possible.

```
import os

os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = "1"

# it is important that the import happens AFTER the line where we set POLARS_MAX_THREADS
import polars as pl
```