Polars: What is the way to limit number of threads on polars?
Polars is consuming all the threads apparently in my app deployed using gunicorn+supervisor. What is the best way to limit the number of threads for polars? I am not reading a csv or writing a csv (using in below code for example only)? also, any way to log the number of threads being consumed by polars at any time?.
├── polars_script.py
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv("input.csv")

# Perform some basic operations
df = df.filter(pl.col("column_name") > 50)  # Filter rows where 'column_name' > 50
df = df.with_column((pl.col("column_name") * 2).alias("new_column"))  # Add a new column

# Write the DataFrame to a new CSV file
df.write_csv("output.csv")

print("Data processing complete. Output saved to output.csv")

├── app.py
from flask import Flask
import polars as pl

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process')
def process_data():
    # Read a CSV file into a Polars DataFrame
    df = pl.read_csv("input.csv")

    # Perform some basic operations
    df = df.filter(pl.col("column_name") > 50)  # Filter rows where 'column_name' > 50
    df = df.with_column((pl.col("column_name") * 2).alias("new_column"))  # Add a new column

    # Write the DataFrame to a new CSV file
    df.write_csv("output.csv")

    return "Data processing complete. Output saved to output.csv"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

├── gunicorn_config.py
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 20



gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py app:app


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179317/how-to-limit-number-of-threads-in-polars?

@Dogbert: Would specifying this in supervisor config work?
